# ModuleNotFoundError: why can't the program find my installed Telegram library?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I am trying to create a Telegram bot so that I can turn off my pc remotely. I've created all the code and everything seems correct, I've also installed all the libraries I use, but the telegram bot library doesn't detect it, I've already tried updating it to the latest version but nothing, it keeps not detecting it. I have followed the step by step guide on [their GitHub](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) several times but nothing changes. Anyway here is the code I programmed and the error it gives me:

Code programmed

```
import telegram
import os
import daemon

# Token
TOKEN = '<My Token>'

# Crea bot
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)

# Funzione bot
def turn_off_pc():
    # Comando di spegnimento
    os.system('shutdown /s /t 0')

# Imput di spegnimento
def handle_message(update, context):
    message = update.message.text
    if message == '/off':
        turn_off_pc()
    else:
        pass

# Gestore comandi bot
def main():
    # Crea il gestore dei comandi del bot
    from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, Updater
    command_handler = CommandHandler('off', handle_message)
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(command_handler)

    # Start in background
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        updater.start_polling()
        updater.idle()

# Avvia bot
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Windows Shutter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import telegram
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'
```

Oh yes, I use Windows 11 22H2 kb5023778 (ty @SUTerliakov)

Comment: Since the problem is related to packages and imports and not your code, please remove unrelated code from the sample (it's not important - only imports do matter here), probably replacing the usage with two-three lines of simplified code. Also, which is more important, provide shell commands you're running (env configuration, package installation, and program invocation, at least), environment used (venv, virtualenv, system-wide, etc.), and OS used.

Answer (score 0):

```
py -m pip install python-telegram-bot
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to run command prompt in administrator mode. To run in administrator mode:

1. Type command prompt in Windows search bar.
2. Right click on the command prompt option and click 'Run as administrator'.
3. Windows will ask you if you want to allow the app to make changes to your device. Click 'Yes'.
4. Command prompt will open in administrator mode.

Then type the following:
`pip install python-telegram-bot`

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the response to everyone, but I have tried all your suggestions and it keeps giving me the same error. I also think it may be a problem with the api version as it's a first version (v. 20.0.0), could it be so?